# Can I have an <img /> fill a fluid square box?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a popular CSS fluid square method in one of my layouts and I'm curious if there is a way to have an image element fill the entire square.

Here is the CSS:

```
.box {
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:100%;
}
```

My HTML would be:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" />
</div>
```

I'd like to have the image fill the box, but as far as I know, padding won't allow for this. Any ideas (other than using a background image.)?

Comment: Have you tried img {width: 100%; height: auto}  ???

Comment: You could try `.box img { width: 100%; }` and then add `overflow: hidden;` to `.box`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `100%` on img

```css
.box {
    background:red;
    width:30%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:30%;
}
.box img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
</div>
```